# What Operator is the Superconformal Index Counting?

Tags: operators, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, superconformality

Given a differential operator $\mathcal{D}$ with adjoint $\mathcal{D}^\dagger$, the analytical index of $\mathcal{D}$ is usually defined by
$$\text{ind }\mathcal{D}=\dim\ker\mathcal{D}-\dim\ker\mathcal{D}^\dagger.$$
Alternatively, we can talk about the superconformal index
$$I(\beta_j) = \mbox{Tr}_{\mathcal{H}}(-1)^F e^{-\gamma\{Q,Q^\dagger\}}e^{-\sum_{j}\beta_j t_j},$$
where $F$ is the fermion number, $Q$ is the supercharge, and $t_j$'s are generators of the Cartan subalgebra of the superconformal and flavor symmetry algebra that commute with $Q$. The superconformal index is the Witten index for superconformal field theories in radial quantization. My question is can I think of the superconformal index $I(\beta_j)$ as counting the analytical index of some operator $\mathcal{D}$? If so, is it the supercharge operator $Q$? Or is it a different operator?